# Multibinding with converter on one of the bindings in .net MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, converters

My issue is that when I use a converter on one of the multibinding's binding.  It doesn't send the right thing to the converter.  As per the DOC(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding?view=net-maui-7.0) in the Consume a IMultiValueConverter it should work, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

My multibinding class is the following:

```
public class BooleanAndConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || !targetType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bool)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            if (!(value is bool b))
            {
                return false;
                
            }
            else if (!b)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

I have a Boolean inverter class which is the following:

```
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then in my XAML I'm using it like so:

```
<Button Text="Passer à la ronde suivante" Command="{Binding NextRoundCommand}">
    <Button.IsVisible>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanAndConverter}">
            <Binding Path="isGameStarted"/>
            <Binding Path="isPlayersPlaying" Converter="{StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.IsVisible>
</Button>
```

When the inverter converter gets called in the multibinding, instead of receiving a TagetType of bool, it receive a "System.object", so it throws the InvalidOperationException.
Why when using normal bindings it receive a targettype of bool and in multibinding it doesn't?

Thanks

Comment: I think a `MultiDataTrigger` would be what you are looking for. It is essentially an `And` operation.  [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: I don't see any significant difference between your code and the doc sample. Try downloading the sameple, and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MathConverter` to do this without a custom `IValueConverter`. MathConverter doesn't support two-way bindings, but if all you need is a one-way binding, you don't need any custom C# converters for this.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathConverter.Maui

Here are a few ways you can do this binding:

1. You can use the `&&` operator (but that makes for some ugly XAML):

```
<Button IsVisible="{math:Convert 'x &amp;&amp; !y',
    x={Binding isGameStarted}, y={Binding isPlayersPlaying}}" ... />
```

2. You can use the built-in `And` function

```
<Button IsVisible="{math:Convert 'And(x, !y)',
    x={Binding isGameStarted}, y={Binding isPlayersPlaying}}" ... />
```

3. You can use a `MathConverter` on a traditional `MultiBinding`.

```
<!-- Define a MathConverter resource: -->
<Application.Resources>
    <math:MathConverter x:Key="Math" />
</Application.Resources>


<!-- Use the MathConverter in a MultiBinding: -->
<Button.IsVisible>
    <MultiBinding ConverterParameter='And(x, !y)' Converter="{StaticResource Math}">
        <Binding Path="isGameStarted"/>
        <Binding Path="isPlayersPlaying"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.IsVisible>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see other code, but I tested the sample code [DataBindingDemos](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/6.0/Fundamentals/DataBindingDemos), it works on my side.

But I found that you didn't implement function `ConvertBack` for both of your (`BooleanAndConverter` and `InverseBooleanConverter` ).

And if I replace the code of `ConvertBack` to yous as follows, the app will throw exception.

```
  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
     throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

You can refer to the following code:

```
 public class InverterConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool? b = value as bool?;
            if (b == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return !b.Value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        }
    }

public class AllTrueMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || !targetType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bool)))
        {
            return false;
            // Alternatively, return BindableProperty.UnsetValue to use the binding FallbackValue
        }

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            if (!(value is bool b))
            {
                return false;
                // Alternatively, return BindableProperty.UnsetValue to use the binding FallbackValue
            }
            else if (!b)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool b) || targetTypes.Any(t => !t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bool))))
        {
            // Return null to indicate conversion back is not possible
            return null;
        }

        if (b)
        {
            return targetTypes.Select(t => (object)true).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            // Can't convert back from false because of ambiguity
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you can check: [AllTrueMultiConverter.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/6.0/Fundamentals/DataBindingDemos/DataBindingDemos/Converters/AllTrueMultiConverter.cs)  and [InverterConverter.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/6.0/Fundamentals/DataBindingDemos/DataBindingDemos/Converters/InverterConverter.cs)

Comment: The question was not how to make it work per se.  I can make my code works just fine if I do not use the variable targetType.  My question was why in multibinding the converter's targetType receives a System.Object instead of a System.Boolean, like it does in a not multibinding binding?  And by asking this question I though it was implied that an answer would also suggest how to make the converter receive a targetType of System.Boolean instead of a Syatem.Object in a multibinding.  Maybe my question wasn't so clear in my original question, sorry.

Comment: I did a test, and I found the `targetType` in `AllTrueMultiConverter` is `System.Boolean` all the time.

Comment: @Philippe, Bindings generally pass the type of the target property targetType to the converter. For example, if you're converting an input to a Label's Text property, the Type of the target property (`Label.Text`) is string, so `targetType` is `typeof(string)`. In your example, there is no target property, since the Binding converted by the `InverseBooleanConverter` is just used as an input to a MultiBinding, which accepts values of type object. Hence, targetType is `typeof(object)`, since the Binding doesn't know that `BooleanAndConverter` should only accept booleans.

Comment: You could imagine a scenario where you want the first Converter to convert a binding of type boolean to type string, and a second Binding then converts the string to type double. Because there's another Binding between the first Binding and the target property, and that intermediary Binding accepts objects of any type, it makes sense for the first Binding to not receive a specific targetType.